# What are the pros and cons of using AppCelerator versus Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, appcelerator

What are the pros and cons of using AppCelerator versus Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cons: I'm presuming Appcelerator falls foul of Apple's recent restrictions of the Developer licensing - You can't develop applications through third party systems.

Comment: That's kind of a big one, yeah.

Comment: Could you perhaps direct me to where it states this in the dev licence?

Comment: I haven't got a copy of the agreement but many commentators and news sites have the details, for example 

http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler

Comment: The signs at the moment are that Appcelerator apps aren't being rejected, so it's still an option for hobbyists.  But it's probably too much of a risk if you are looking to invest a bit of money in an app.

Answer (score 1):

CON:

When working behind a corporate firewall there are proxy issues with the application logging you in and therefore you find yourself in a position that you can't use it or your locked out of your project.

I had it working but now it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Objective C is probably a more verbose and low-level approach, you may see that as a good or bad thing. Appcelerator lets you develop in Javascript which is a simpler syntax. Objective C targets iPhone only, with Appcelerator the same codebase will produce an app that works on Android too, or near as dammit.

The licensing issues with Apple appear to have been resolved for the time being, however with Redmond being what it is who knows what the future will bring.